# How to reference jboss-client.jar as a module?

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

I'm using jboss 7.1.1.final and i have a logging module i wrote that extends `org.jboss.logmanager.ExtHandler` and writes logs to DB, problem is that ExtHandler class is in jboss-client.jar which is under JBOSS_HOME/bin/client.

So i need to reference it from my logging module, but copying it under modules seems wrong as it creates a duplication, is there a better way of letting my logging module know it depends on this jar?

Here is my module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Represents the OG-Logging module -->
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mycomp">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="OG-Logging-1.0.jar" />
    </resources>

    <dependencies>

        <system export="false">
            <paths>
                <path name="javax/naming" />
                <path name="javax/naming/directory" />
                <path name="javax/naming/event" />
                <path name="javax/naming/ldap" />
                <path name="javax/naming/spi" />
                <path name="javax/sql" />
            </paths>
        </system>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.lang" />
        <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: read the JBOSS_HOME/bin/client/README.txt

Long answer:

Add these deps to your module.xml:

```
org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging
org.jboss.logmanager:jboss-logmanager
```